# Custom cursors in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I'm creating a custom cursor for a site. I've gotten two divs centered to the cursor when the mouse moves but when I hover on an anchor tag the position of the background cursor is off. I've tried using pageX and pageY to center it in the for loop but it doesn't seem to work. Help?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <div class="cursor"></div>
    <div class="cursor-bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    .cursor{
        height:10px;
        width:10px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:absolute;
        background: #fff;
        z-index: 100;

    }

    .cursor-bg{
        height:30px;
        :30px;
        border-radius:50%;
        position:absolute;
        background: $lightCursor-bg;
        transition-duration: 400ms;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;

    }

    .expand{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        border:solid 1px #fff;
        background: rgba(255,255,255, 0);
    }
```

JS:

```
    (function(){
        var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
        var cursorBg = document.querySelector('.cursor-bg');
        var navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a');

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            cursor.style.left = (e.pageX - 5) + 'px';
            cursor.style.top = (e.pageY - 5) + 'px';
            cursorBg.style.left = (e.pageX - 15) + 'px';
            cursorBg.style.top = (e.pageY -15) + 'px';

        });

       for (var i = 0; i < navLinks.length; i++) {

              var singleLink = navLinks[i];
              singleLink.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
                  cursorBg.classList.add("expand");
                  cursorBg.style.left = (e.pageX - 50) + 'px';
                  cursorBg.style.left = (e.pageY - 50) + 'px';
              })

              singleLink.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
                  cursorBg.classList.remove("expand");
              })
       }

     })();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `cursor` property for this:

`cursor: url(https://example.com/your-image.png), auto`

Demo:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
}

.custom-cursor {
  background: red;
  cursor: url('https://i.imgur.com/ng6jKDk.png'), auto
}

p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-cursor">
<p>Custom Cursor in this div only!</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>Not in this div!</p>
</div>
```

If you want the cursor to apply to the entire page, just add the css to the body.

[CSS cursor property](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/)

Comment: I'm trying to get the position of the background div to be centered around the mouse when I hover over a link. All other styles are working except the stye:left; in loops