# Update cursor icon during scrolling (Touchpad)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to replicate this scroll/cursor behaviour: https://www.nessalab.com/

As you can see, the cursor icon changes according to what is hovered even during scrolling. You don't have to stop scrolling see the change of the cursor.

I've inspected the source of this page but it seems like it's not done by JavaScript.
Is there some magical CSS property for this?

Comment: Do you mean when the cursor changes to "view case study"?  Looks like a custom cursor to me...   here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59445141/2181514

Comment: @freedomn-m not really. Cursor changes also when you hover text, link, whatever. But it changes WHILE you scroll, not after you stop scrolling.

Comment: What part of the page and its related cursor are you interested in? For example, for the image towards the bottom the cursor: pointer setting is in the CSS for that element. Have a look at all the CSS and the computed styles for cursor using your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see if you can find what you want.

Comment: @AHaworth I'm not interested in how the cursor looks like. I'm interested in how the cursor changes without moving the mouse. It changes on scroll. Weather you scroll through text, link or image it changes while scrolling.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I still don't see what the problem is. If I scroll (e.g by using the keyboard arrows) with the cursor positioned over an element it shows the correct type of cursor for that element, and as I scroll some more, without stopping, if I pass over another element it shows the correct cursor for that element. As I said, the cursor type is set in the CSS for the various elements. Could you explain some more what the problem is?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm sending a loom https://www.loom.com/share/7bc5ba9f5d4e43bb9367052a1dcbc0ee

First site: stackoverflow - when there is one cursor active (pointer) and you scroll (touchpad) without moving the cursor out of the link (cursor: pointer) the cursor stays the same. You have to move the cursor to change it.

Second site: nessalab.com - you dont have to move the cursor, it changes just on scroll, without moving the mouse.

Comment: What browser/OS are you on - I can scroll up and down Stack Overflow without stopping and the cursor changes depending what it's over-but I'm using arrow keys to scroll. Is that the difference?

Comment: @AHaworth I'm using Arc (Chromium) browser on OSX. And yes, I think that this issue is related to touchpad scrolling.

Comment: Yes, sorry to be a bit slow. On windows10/Edge I too see no change in the cursor while scrolling on the touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

It just changes cursor to custom one when hovering over element, so no need to stop:

```css
.inner {
  cursor: url('https://assets.website-files.com/6284f50b95ff173d79dff367/62c80529166a88056c167a29_see-cs-big.svg'), auto;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 30px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="inner"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: As OP pointed out, it appears custom cursors only change when the mouse moves, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/8wo72fjn/

Comment: Yeah as you can see, you have to stop scrolling to see the custom cursor. you dont have to do this on the site I've posted

Comment: @xmigas I see same effect on your provided page (e.g. when fast scrolling through that page part). And there is no other events except mousedown/mouseup